# Focusing & Reading of Main Page Heading Tag when navigated in Angular

Tags: angular, navigation, screen-readers, html-heading, nvda

**Objective:** Heading tags or main land mark should be read by NVDA screen reader when navigating from one page to another

**Observed Behaviour:** Heading tags are not read by screen reader when navigated.
But whenever reload/refresh occurs screen reader reads the heading tags

**Expected Behaviour:** After navigating from one page to another heading tags must be read

```
<h1 tabindex="-1">
    Some Heading
</h1>
```

---

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.readMainLandMark();
}

readMainLandMark() {
    // console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0]); // Results undefined because of HTMLCollection is []
    this.router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe(() => {
        const mainHeaders = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
        if(mainHeaders.length !== 0) {
            mainHeaders[0].focus();
        }
    });
}
```

Here `NavigationEnd` Recognizes the previous instance page heading context. So after loading/refresh again screen reader reads the current page heading considering previous page as the current page that's the reason why after reloading the same page heading tags are read. But not when navigated...

How to accomplish reading of heading tags when navigated from one page to another?

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1 id="main-content-header" tabindex="-1">
    Some Heading Name
</h1>
```

---

```
readMainLandMark() {
    this._router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe(() => {
        const mainHeader = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('#main-content-header');
        if (mainHeader) {
          (mainHeader as HTMLElement)?.focus();
        }
    });
}
```